# Git Difftool p4merge Unexpected Prompt on Diff

Tags: bash, git, macos, command-line-interface, p4merge

When running `git difftool` I am being prompted for file diff, even though I have `prompt = false` in my .gitconfig file.

**Snippet from .gitconfig**

```
[diff]
  tool = p4mergetool
  renames = copies
  mnemonicprefix = true
[difftool "p4mergetool"]
  cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
  keepBackup = false
  keepTemporaries = false
  trustExitCode = false
  prompt = false
```

My .gitconfig entries were based on [this answer on the Ask Different exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346038/320322).

**macOS Terminal Output** (bash)

> $ git difftool factory-test HEAD -- $(git difftool factory-test HEAD --name-only *.c *.h) 
> Viewing (1/13): 'factory_test/config/sl_spidrv_usart_spidrv_config.h' 
> Launch 'p4mergetool' [Y/n]? Y 
> Viewing (2/13): 'factory_test/app.c' 
> Launch 'p4mergetool' [Y/n]?

How do I get the prompt suppression to take effect?

My version infos:

- p4merge (Rev. Helix Merge/MACOSX1015X86_64/2021.1/2085655)
- git (git version 2.31.1)
- macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
[diff]
  tool = p4mergetool
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[difftool "p4mergetool"]
  cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
  keepBackup = false
  keepTemporaries = false
  trustExitCode = false
```